# GTM add event parameter to dom ready trigger

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a tag in gtm with an event parameter which can be true or false. This tag is triggerd by a domReady (or page loaded) trigger on a specific URL. Inside the DOM I have an element that has inside a div-Tag the attribute `data-ga-confirmation="true"` or `data-ga-confirmation="false"`.

The variable is not given to GTM though, the event parameter of the tag always has the default value.

For click triggers it works fine, but there I can add the `data-ga-confirmation="true"` attribute to the element I'm actually clicking on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a CJS variable in GTM. Like so:

```js
function(){
  return {{Clicked Element}}.getAttribute("data-ga-confirmation");
}
```

And use it in your tag. Since you've not provided your HTML, I assume we're talking about the attribute on the clicked element. Well if no, you can always parse your way through GTM from the clicked element.